# How can I get all the transaction from a nft collection?

Tags: node, api, nft, tzstats

Hello Tezos community,

I am currently working on wash trading on NFTs.

Being a fan of Tezos and seeing the explosion of NFTs on Tezos, and the upcoming Mumbai update, I'd like to retrieve data on transactions from certain collections to study the proportion of fake trades.

Would you advise me to use the Tzstats APIs or to install the blockchain directly locally?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the TzKT api for this, check it out at https://api.tzkt.io/

As a rough sample you could use something like this:

https://api.tzkt.io/v1/accounts/KT1CzVSa18hndYupV9NcXy3Qj7p8YFDZKVQv/operations?limit=10

Where `KT1CzVSa18hndYupV9NcXy3Qj7p8YFDZKVQv` is the address of the contract (in this case, mooncakes). Depending on what you are trying to do, you may need to deal with pagination, rate limits, excluding certain types of transactions etc, which can be done with the API, but you will need to poke around the docs

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you TzKT API: [api.tzkt.io](https://api.tzkt.io), because it's more flexible and has richer functionality.

I don't know, how exactly you are going to "study the proportion of fake trades", but in general, you would need this endpoint: [/v1/operations/transactions](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetTransactions), which can give you all transactions, filtered by sender/target (e.g. a particular NFT marketplace contract), parameters (e.g. particular tokens/collections/orders), and other things.

Also, you can use this endpoint [/v1/tokens/transfers](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Tokens_GetTokenTransfers) to work with high-level entities, representing token transfers, or this endpoint [/v1/bigmaps/updates](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/BigMaps_GetBigMapUpdates) to work with low-level entities, representing changes in contracts storages. All of these also have various query filters.

As for the installing of the blockchain node locally, it won't help, because the node RPC doesn't have the functionality for your needs. The only way is to use an indexer, like TzKT, that can also be installed locally, as it is [open-source](https://github.com/baking-bad/tzkt).